# Deleting temp files through Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, groovy, resource-cleanup

I have Selenium Hub and Jenkins node on the same machine. 
I want to cleanup the `%Temp%` directory before each jenkins build.

Is there a better way to do this. I am trying to use `Hudson` import in the build code, but it is cleaning up the workspace folders but not the `TEMP` directory on windows.

I tried a couple of things like 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tmp+Cleaner+Plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delete+.tmp+files+left+in+workspace-files

But I was not able to achieve what I was looking for.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can make a simple `powershell` script or a `bat` script that deletes what you want in the directory, include the script it in your project, and call it as a build step in `Jenkins`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked :)

Comment: @user1658435 Can you please post the powershell command that you have used to run from the jenkins job that would clean up the Temp files and folders.